# Opening a Rich Modal Panel on Button Click

Tags: jsf

I m trying to open a rich modal panel with populated data on a button click

tried

```
<h:commandButton id="btn_search" value="#{text['button.add']}" 
                    action="#{cartBean.search}"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('dlg_results')}.show()">                            
                    </h:commandButton>
```

and

```
<h:commandButton id="btn_search" value="#{text['button.add']}" 
                    action="#{cartBean.search}" immediate="true">
                        <rich:componentControl for="dlg_results" attachTo="btn_search" operation="show" event="onclick"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
```

This code opens the model panel on button click but when response is sent back from the server the whole page gets refreshed

can some one suggest a way to handle this ???

Answer (score 2):

Use `<a4j:commandButton>` instead of `h:commandButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this was helpful information.

I used `showWhenRendered` tag in `rich:modalpanel` to solve my problem. I added a variable in my bean and set its value to true on click of button if records are found.